# Error when trying to create this MySQL table. What's incorrect?

Tags: mysql

The following image shows the error I'm getting. What am I doing wrong?

http://tinypic.com/r/2vabf3c/8

When I try to add the following to a new table through the command line to a mysql database I get the following error shown in the image.

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
my_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
analysis_sample_rate FLOAT NOT NULL,
artist_7digitalid INT NOT NULL,
artist_familiarity FLOAT NOT NULL,
artist_hotttnesss FLOAT NOT NULL,
artist_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
artist_latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
artist_location VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
artist_longitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
artist_mbid VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
artist_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
artist_playmeid INT NOT NULL,
audio_md5 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
danceability FLOAT NOT NULL,
duration FLOAT NOT NULL,
end_of_fade_in FLOAT NOT NULL,
energy FLOAT NOT NULL,
key_of_song INT NOT NULL,
key_confidence FLOAT NOT NULL,
loudness FLOAT NOT NULL,
mode INT NOT NULL,
mode_confidence FLOAT NOT NULL,
album_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
release_7digitalid INT NOT NULL,
song_hotttnesss FLOAT NOT NULL,
song_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
tempo FLOAT NOT NULL,
time_signature INT NOT NULL,
time_signature_confidence FLOAT NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
track_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
track_7digitalid INT NOT NULL,
year INT NOT NULL);
```

I have corrected the usage of key and of request however I still am getting an error.

http://tinypic.com/r/2akl6q8/8

Comment: Please post your creation-query.

Comment: Are any of your column names reserved words?  Like `key` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the word "key" for a column name since it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

You can however, still use it, but you must escape it with backticks, like so:

```
...
`key` INT NOT NULL,
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change mode's parameter name. Probably, mode is a reserved keyword.

Comment: "probably" is not good enough. you can trivially check this yourself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html  and as it turns out, you're wrong.